# TransientFaultHandling: ApplicationConfiguration class missing?

Tags: c#, azure

On all these links:

http://michaelwasham.com/2011/11/14/handy-library-for-dealing-with-transient-connectivity-in-the-cloud/

http://community.adxstudio.com/Default.aspx?DN=56cfea23-199b-4a59-ac68-7eb24de78760

http://convective.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/handling-transient-connection-failures-in-sql-azure/

they use:

```
 // Retrieve the retry policy settings from the application configuration file.
 RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings retryPolicySettings = ApplicationConfiguration.Current.GetConfigurationSection<RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings>(RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings.SectionName);

// Retrieve the required retry policy definition by its friendly name.
 RetryPolicyInfo retryPolicyInfo = retryPolicySettings.Policies.Get(“FixedIntervalDefault”);

// Create an instance of the respective retry policy using the transient error detection strategy for SQL Azure.
 RetryPolicy sqlAzureRetryPolicy = retryPolicyInfo.CreatePolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>();
```

I cant find the ApplicationConfiguration class nor RetryPolicyInfo class. What references am I missing?

Thanks,
Stevo

Comment: I believe these are part of the Enterprise library and the additional Enterprise library Azure pack: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28189